# Does using nullif() statements with xquery in SQL Server ruin xquery optimization?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, query-optimization, xquery

I have the following block of dynamic SQL in SQL Server 2008 (as part of a larger query):

```
insert into '+@schema+'.HP_Payers (HeadingID, PayerName, PayerID_Qualifier, PayerID, Address1, Address2, City, StateCode, ZipCode)
        select @headingID as HeadingID,
            nullif(c.value(''Name'', ''varchar(60)''), '''') as PayerName,
            nullif(c.value(''ID_Qualifier'', ''varchar(2)''), '''') as PayerID_Qualifier,
            nullif(c.value(''ID_Code'', ''varchar(80)''), '''') as PayerID,
            nullif(c.value(''Address1'', ''varchar(55)''), '''') as Address1,
            nullif(c.value(''Address2'', ''varchar(55)''), '''') as Address2,
            nullif(c.value(''City'', ''varchar(30)''), '''') as City,
            nullif(c.value(''StateCode'', ''char(2)''), '''') as StateCode,
            nullif(c.value(''ZipCode'', ''varchar(15)''), '''') as ZipCode
        from '+@schema+'.IntegrationQueue cross apply InputValue.nodes(''/ROOT/Payer'') t(c)
        where QueueID = @queueID
```

which inserts the correct data from the given node in the 'from' statement into a new table. The entire query itself ran a set of 10 XML files about 10 seconds faster than it did before I added the nullif() statements. I also found this tidbit of info on MS documentation regarding xquery optimization:

*The value() method calls must appear contiguously in a SELECT list to be merged. The execution of non-contiguous value() methods are not combined.*

So my question is does placing these nullif() statements essentially ruin this performance gain described here? Any help would be appreciated.